# replace element at an index of an array then reset array using for loop

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I want to update only 1 element in the 1d array and then start over fresh. if viewed as a matrix form I just want entries i = j to be changed.

my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

for i, j in enumerate(a):
    b = a
    b[i] = j + 1
    print(b)
```

I want each iteration of the for loop to only change one element and keep everything else the same.

the output I want looks like this:

```
[11, 20, 30, 40, 50]
[10, 21, 30, 40, 50]
[10, 20, 31, 40, 50]
[10, 20, 30, 41, 50]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 51]
```

but I'm getting this because b is not resetting even though I am (or at lest i think) restoring the original array at the start of each loop.

```
[11, 20, 30, 40, 50]
[11, 21, 30, 40, 50]
[11, 21, 31, 40, 50]
[11, 21, 31, 41, 50]
[11, 21, 31, 41, 51]
```

any ideas where I went wrong? TIA

Comment: Replace `b=a` with `b=a.copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `b=a` with `b=a.copy()`
`b=a`, will create `b` and point to the same memory. Whereas `b=a.copy()`, creates a `copy of a` and stores it as `b` in different memory location.